# Laravel 5.4 Multiple upload and Inserting data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello everyone and thank you in advance, first of all sorry if my code is so confused I am still learning ^^.
I am trying to make a product with different attribute plus 3 different images(making the product gallery) and a feature image,
I have succeed to create the attributes and feature image.
The problem is with the 3 image for the gallery I cant store (neither in DB or image folder)
I have Two tables (product and productgallery) the relation between them is hasMany (I am using Laravel 5.4)

This the error I got after run the code

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `product_galleries` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-05-13 20:58:20, 2017-05-13 20:58:20))
```

(sorry for my English which for sure will make it harder to understand my question)

ProductController

```
 public function store(UploadRequest $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->product_name = $request->product_name;
        $product->product_description = $request->product_description;
        if($request->hasFile('product_preview')) {
          $file = Input::file('product_preview');
          $filename = time(). '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
          $product->product_preview = $filename;
          $file->move(public_path().'/images/product-feature', $filename);
        }
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->color_id = $request->color_id;
        $product->size_id = $request->size_id;
        $product->material_id = $request->material_id;
        // $product->fantasia_id = $request->fantasia_id;
        $productgallery = new ProductGallery();
        if($request->hasFile('fileToUpload[]')) {
          $files = Input::file('fileToUpload[]');
          foreach ($request->$files as $photo) {
            $filename = time(). '-' .$photo->getClientOriginalName();
            $productgallery->product_images = $filename;
            $photo->move(public_path().'/images/product-gallery', $filename);
            $productgallery->product_id = 1;
          }
        }
        $product->save();
        $productgallery->save();
        return $this->create()->with('success', 'Uploaded Successfully');
    }
```

Upload request (FormRequest)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UploadRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
          'product_name'  => 'required|max:120',
          'category_id'   => 'required|integer',
          'product_preview' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ];
        $fileToUpload = count($this->input('fileToUpload'));
        foreach(range(0, $fileToUpload) as $index) {
            $rules['fileToUpload.' . $index] = 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:2000';
        }
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

the view for the form

```
@extends('layouts.backend-master')

@section('styles')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
@endsection

@section('content')

  @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
     </div>
  @endif

  <h1>Add a new product</h1>
  <form action="{{route('products.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="product_name">Name of the product</label>
      <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="product_description">Product Description</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="product_preview">Feature Image:</label>
      <input type="file" name="product_preview" id="file">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="category_id">Category</label>
      <select name="category_id" id="category_id">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
          <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="color_id">Color</label>
      <select name="color_id" id="color_id">
        @foreach($colors as $color)
          <option value="{{ $color->id }}">{{ $color->color_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="size_id">Size</label>
      <select name="size_id" id="size_id">
        @foreach($sizes as $size)
          <option value="{{ $size->id }}">{{ $size->size_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="material_id">Material</label>
      <select name="material_id" id="material_id">
        @foreach($materials as $material)
          <option value="{{ $material->id }}">{{ $material->material_type }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Product Gallery:</label>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple >
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
  </form>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
@endsection
```

thank you

Comment: The error that you get above is saying that you are trying to make an insert to a db table that has product_id as a field but you have not made it so there is a default value. So its causing an error. Either change that field to have a default value ( assuming 0 ) or it you always want to make sure it has a value you need to make sure to include one when inserting. Is that your primary ID? If so did you forget to make it auto increment?

Comment: I want product_id to be populate automatically with the ID of the product table @scott

Comment: Basically I want to know how to have one form that submits the data to the appropriate tables and assign the ID of the product table to the product_id (foreign key) in the product-gallery table   @Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look at Laravel relationships API documentation. Here's a link to read more about it [Laravel 5.4 Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

---

***Quick tip to fix that***

You should add a foreign key in your database/migration file

 For a migration you can simply add

```
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
```

And add this method to your **Product** model

```
public function productgallery(){
 return $this->hasMany(Productgallery::class);
}
```

and this to your **Productgallery** model

```
public function product(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

*Note: You'll still need to populate the `product_id` field within your request*

---

***Package solution***

I'd recommend you use a 3rd party package for that matter, as it will be less work, cleaner and more solid to use.
You can look more into [spatie's medialibrary for Laravel](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary)

Comment: thank you for answering, I did all that, the thing I cant do is how to populate `product_id` @Rezrazi, I tried this `$productgallery->products()->associate($product);`
      `$productgallery->product_id = $request->id;` but no luck

Comment: You could use `attach` or simply within your request, add `$productgallery->product_id = $product->id`
I'd recommend you use the `create` method for your models, the `new` isn't that much recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

This will create a new `Product` and create a new `ProductGallery` for each image passed in `$request->file('fileToUpload[]')`:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->product_name = $request->product_name;
$product->product_description = $request->product_description;
if($request->hasFile('product_preview')) {
  $file = Input::file('product_preview');
  $filename = time(). '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
  $product->product_preview = $filename;
  $file->move(public_path().'/images/product-feature', $filename);
}
$product->category_id = $request->category_id;
$product->color_id = $request->color_id;
$product->size_id = $request->size_id;
$product->material_id = $request->material_id;
// $product->fantasia_id = $request->fantasia_id;


// First save the product (so that you have it's ID)
$product->save();
// Then create galleries
if($request->hasFile('fileToUpload[]')) {
  $files = Input::file('fileToUpload[]');
  foreach ($files as $photo) {
    $productgallery = new ProductGallery();
    $filename = time(). '-' .$photo->getClientOriginalName();
    $productgallery->product_images = $filename;
    $photo->move(public_path().'/images/product-gallery', $filename);
    $productgallery->product_id = $product->id; // Save it to the newly created product
    $productgallery->save();
  }
}
return $this->create()->with('success', 'Uploaded Successfully');
```

Comment: Thanks dev but I updated the code but still not working. @dev, do you think my validation is ok ?

Comment: it execute the first part of the code saving the new product, but it doesnt go to the second part at all thus it doesnt the galleries , I also added `$productgallery = new ProductGallery();` to the code but no luck @dev

Comment: This happens because you're not sending any files in your `Input::file('filesToUpload[]')` array. Why I don't know. But your backend code should work like this I think.